# how to update value in csr_matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have created a csr_matrix of size 16^4 and 16^8. But I need to update the value in csr_matrix, So how can I update the value in sparse matrix.

I have also tried `twoByte.toarray()[i] += 1`, `twoByte.toarray()[0][i] += 1` and `twoByte[0].toarray()[i] += 1` but it does not work. below is the code snippet.

```
feature_matrix_two = csr_matrix((len(files),16**4),dtype=int)
feature_matrix_four = csr_matrix((len(files),16**6),dtype=int)

k=0

byte_feature_file=open('bigramresult.csv','w+')

for file in files:
    byte_feature_file.write(file+",")
    if(file.endswith("txt")):
        with open('byteFiles/'+file,"r") as byte_code:
            twoByte = csr_matrix((1,16**4),dtype = int)
            fourByte = csr_matrix((1,16**8),dtype = int)
            for row in byte_code:
                codes = row.rstrip().split(" ")
                codes_2g = codes[:-1]
                codes_4g = codes[:-2]
                for i in range(len(codes_2g)):
                    codes_2g[i] += codes[i+1]
                for i in range(len(codes_4g)):
                    codes_4g[i] += codes[i+1]+codes[i+2]

                twoByteCode = []
                for i in codes_2g:
                    if '??' not in i:
                        twoByteCode += [int(i,16)]
                fourByteCode = []
                for i in codes_4g:
                    if '??' not in i:
                        fourByteCode += [int(i,16)]

                for i in twoByteCode:
                    twoByte[i] += 1

                for i in fourByteCode:
                    fourByte[i] += 1
            byte_code.close()
            feature_matrix_two[k] = twoByte
            feature_matrix_four[k] = fourByte

    for i in feature_matrix_two[k]:
        byte_feature_file.write(str(i)+",")
    for i in feature_matrix_four[k]:
        byte_feature_file.write(str(i)+",")

    byte_feature_file.write("\n")
    k+=1
```

Comment: Have you read the `scipy.sparse` documentation, especially for `csr` (but also `lil`)?  And have you played with small matrices, say (1,10) or (10,10) shape?  I don't think you should be jumping to make big arrays like from `csv` files right away.  What was your starting point?  some 'machine-learning' tutorial?

Comment: yes, I read the documentation but didn't found it usefull for this query. I tried first on small size array of (1,16) but It does not work.

Comment: A sparse matrix is 2d (by definition) and you created it as (1,N) shape.  `twoByte[0,n] = 1` sets an element to 1 (but you will get an warning).  Since the first dimension is 1, the only allowable index is 0.  But in general you should not set or increment element values of a `csr` matrix one by one.  That format is not designed for that.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html shows how to construct a csr matrix incrementally.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, I think you don't need sparse matrix, you can use a dict object, for example:

```
from collections import defaultdict 
twoByte = defaultdict(int)
fourByte = defaultdict(int)
```